# Emacs/Gnus 24.3 -- invisible groups

Tags: gnus

I configured Gnus to fetch mails from gmail account, and it works well, I can send and receive messages. However, one thing I'd like to improve is ability to add `C-u 5 M-x gnus-group-list-all-groups` command in my ~/.gnus so that I don't need to press the key combination every time I run Gnus. What should I add in config file to achieve this? Thanks.

Comment: Please do not cross-post to both this site and StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1):

```
(with-eval-after-load 'gnus-group
  (gnus-group-list-all-groups 5))
```

in modern GNU Emacs or

```
 (eval-after-load 'gnus-group
   '(gnus-group-list-all-groups 5))
```

in outdated GNU Emacs older than 24.4 (your case).